# DistinctResultList in OpenJPA

Tags: openjpa

I am attempting to get a distinct list of id's back that would be longs... But I am getting back this DistinctResultList... How can one handle this so that they get back results they are expecting... Here is what I am doing...

```
@NamedQuery(name="getProvidersByResourceIds", query = "SELECT DISTINCT p.resourceId FROM Provider p WHERE p.resourceId `in :resourceIds")`
```

Out of that I try and get the resourceIds' by doing this...

```
List<Long> provIDs = (List<Long>) emf.createNamedQuery("getProvidersByResourceIds").setParameter("resourceIds", values).getResultList();
```

But like I said, I keep getting back a DistinctResultList... Looking through the debugger, I can see the values I am getting back.  How can I translate this into something usefull?

```
javax.ejb.EJBException: See nested exception; nested exception is: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter "Parameter<long>('resourceIds')" declared in "SELECT p FROM Provider p WHERE p.resourceId = :resourceIds" is set to value of "org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DistinctResultList@35fb35fb" of type "org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DistinctResultList", but this parameter is bound to a field of type "long".
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter "Parameter<long>('resourceIds')" declared in "SELECT p FROM Provider p WHERE p.resourceId = :resourceIds" is set to value of "org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DistinctResultList@35fb35fb" of type "org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DistinctResultList", but this parameter is bound to a field of type "long"
```

Comment: > How can I translate this into something useful? What do you mean by this? You executed a query to return a List of Longs, and that is what was returned to you.

Comment: Nope, I am getting something called a DistinctResultList...  I have no idea what to do with this return result

Comment: ... and a DistinctResultList is a List. Unless you plan on streaming this result to some other JVM that doesn't have the OpenJPA binaries on the classpath, the List implementation should not matter. Please enlighten me if you disagree.

Comment: While it is a list, it does not appear to be a list of Long's as I was expecting.  Because when I try and use it in an object that takes a list of longs, I get a type mismatch error...

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: Edited comments to show the exception... I think I may have figured out what is wrong though.  Amazing what a good nights sleep and a complete breakfast featuring kellogs (r) Raisin Bran can do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query to :

```
@NamedQuery(name="getProvidersByResourceIds", 
    query = "SELECT DISTINCT p.resourceId FROM Provider p WHERE p.resourceId in (:resourceIds)");
```

Comment: Yep... That is what I did.  And it seems to work, but now I am getting timeouts when I try and get all the data back...

Comment: I had 3.  But it could be possible to put in many more.  I don't think that is the problem though, I had a statement or two in there with a new ArrayList of HashSet()... I got rid of that, and now I am still getting timeouts...

Comment: I was attempting to return a non-serializable object to a method that serializes objects and the expected result happens.  Cleared that up and everything seems like it is working.